# Minikube can't pull image from local registry

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I ran `eval $(minikube docker-env)` then built a docker container. When I run `docker images` on my host I can see the image. When I run `minikube ssh` then `docker images` I can see it.

When I try to run it, the pod fails to launch. `kubectl describe pod` gives:

```
14m     3m      7   kubelet, minikube   spec.containers{quoting-crab-customer-refresh-cache-cron}   Normal      Pulling         pulling image "personalisation-customer:latest"
14m     3m      7   kubelet, minikube   spec.containers{quoting-crab-customer-refresh-cache-cron}   Warning     Failed          Failed to pull image "personalisation-customer:latest": rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: image library/personalisation-customer:latest not found
14m     2s      66  kubelet, minikube                                   Warning     FailedSync      Error syncing pod
14m     2s      59  kubelet, minikube   spec.containers{quoting-crab-customer-refresh-cache-cron}   Normal      BackOff         Back-off pulling image "personalisation-customer:latest"
```

My `imagePullPolicy` is `Always`.

What could be causing this? Other pods are working locally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You aren't exactly pulling from your local registry, you are using your previously downloaded images or your locally builded, since you are specifying `imagePullPolicy: Always` this will always try to pull it from the registry.

Your image doesn't contain a specific docker registry `personalisation-customer:latest` for what docker will understand `index.docker.io/personalisation-customer:latest` and this is an image that doesn't exist in the public docker registry.

So you have 2 options `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` or to upload the image to some registry.

Comment: You sir, deserve a beer. I did not interpret the docs correctly and you saved me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The local Docker cache isn't a registry. Kubernetes tries to download the image from Dockerhub (the default registry), since you set `iMagePullPolicy` to `Always`. Set it to `Never`, so Kubernetes uses to local image.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Issue was not mentioning the image version. I used

```
kubectl run testapp1 --image=<image> --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
```

instead of,

```
kubectl run testapp1 --image=<image>:<version> --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent
```

Answer (score 1):

For minikube, make the changes as follows:

1. Eval the docker env using:
   eval $(minikube docker-env)
2. Build the docker image:
   docket build -t my-image
3. Set the image name as only "my-image" in pod specification in your yaml file.
4. Set the imagePullPolicy to Never in you yaml file. Here is the example:

   ```
   apiVersion:
   kind:
   metadata:
   spec:
     template:
        metadata:
           labels:
              app: my-image
     spec:
        containers:
          - name: my-image
          image: "my-image"
          imagePullPolicy: Never
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh to minikube using ssh

```
minikube ssh -p <profilename>
```

and then pull the image

```
docker pull <image>
```

Make sure the `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`

and then run your deployment